# Fetching Facebook user data with JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This really is a newbie question but I've been struggling on it for hours, so any help is welcome.

I'm trying to fetch the Facebook user data after the user's authentication. Basically I just want the name and profile picture, but I can't seem to find a way to fetch these data.

Right after my body tag, I have the following code:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '270033680024381',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.6'
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '<p>Autenticação realizada com sucesso!</p> <br> <br> <p> Escreva sua proposta abaixo.</p> ';
          document.getElementById('login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '<p> Você não está autenticado. Por favor, faça o login.</p> <div onclick="login()"> Logar </div>'
        } else {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '<p> Você não está autenticado. Por favor, faça o login.</p> <div onclick="login()"> Logar </div>';
        }
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
  }

  FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name'}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });


  </script>
```

The authentication feature works great. But the problem is when I'm fetching the user data. I don't know how to do that, I've seen on the Facebook Developers page the code:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name'}, function(response) {
console.log(response);
```

});

But when I go to the console log, it says FB is undefined. I can't find a way to print those datas on my page also. What I want to do is to pass the name and profile picture values to a form. Could someone please help me on that?

Comment: I think I've just found out how to print the data, but when I print it, it says that the data is 'undefined'.

Comment: In your code, you are trying to call FB.api before the SDK is initialized, and that’s why you get that error. (If you have changed this by now, then please update your question to reflect the current state of your code.)

Comment: Yes, I have updated it and now that part works fine. The only problem is at printing the profile picture in a div. I'm trying to print it with this code, but it only shows the URL on the page, not the proper image:

document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.id + "/picture?type=large";

Comment: Wow, I just had to put that link inside a <img> tag. Thanks for the help @CBroe! Problem fixed. :)